Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent. not using redirects
I have an aspx.net page that has 3 update panels in it. When I select the items in update panel one, update panel 3 fills with a gridview. Under update panel 1 there is update panel 2 which is like a search function with 2 buttons. Panel 3 has the gridview which also has buttons. Panel 1 has 3 drop downs and a calendar which fills the gridview.
When I fill the gridview and click any of the buttons I get the following error:

System.Web.HttpException   HResult=0x80004005   Message=Cannot
redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.
Source=App_global.asax.mdn7vulq

Is there a reason that using 3 update panels would cause such an error?

I think I found the issue. It was breaking because there were a few labels with the same "Id" but it crashed giving that generic error. I fixed the labels and now all the buttons work.
